# When I execute this query in my Jupyter Notebook it shows me error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Query:

```
df['Date/Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date/Time'], format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in _to_datetime_with_format(arg, orig_arg, name, tz, fmt, exact, errors, infer_datetime_format)
    508         try:
--> 509             values, tz = conversion.datetime_to_datetime64(arg)
    510             dta = DatetimeArray(values, dtype=tz_to_dtype(tz))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\tslibs\conversion.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.datetime_to_datetime64()

TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_8924/3560383786.py in <module>
----> 1 df['Date/Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date/Time'], format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in to_datetime(arg, errors, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, format, exact, unit, infer_datetime_format, origin, cache)
    885             result = arg.map(cache_array)
    886         else:
--> 887             values = convert_listlike(arg._values, format)
    888             result = arg._constructor(values, index=arg.index, name=arg.name)
    889     elif isinstance(arg, (ABCDataFrame, abc.MutableMapping)):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in _convert_listlike_datetimes(arg, format, name, tz, unit, errors, infer_datetime_format, dayfirst, yearfirst, exact)
    391 
    392     if format is not None:
--> 393         res = _to_datetime_with_format(
    394             arg, orig_arg, name, tz, format, exact, errors, infer_datetime_format
    395         )

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in _to_datetime_with_format(arg, orig_arg, name, tz, fmt, exact, errors, infer_datetime_format)
    511             return DatetimeIndex._simple_new(dta, name=name)
    512         except (ValueError, TypeError):
--> 513             raise err
    514 
    515 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in _to_datetime_with_format(arg, orig_arg, name, tz, fmt, exact, errors, infer_datetime_format)
    498 
    499         # fallback
--> 500         res = _array_strptime_with_fallback(
    501             arg, name, tz, fmt, exact, errors, infer_datetime_format
    502         )

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in _array_strptime_with_fallback(arg, name, tz, fmt, exact, errors, infer_datetime_format)
    434 
    435     try:
--> 436         result, timezones = array_strptime(arg, fmt, exact=exact, errors=errors)
    437         if "%Z" in fmt or "%z" in fmt:
    438             return _return_parsed_timezone_results(result, timezones, tz, name)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\tslibs\strptime.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.array_strptime()

ValueError: time data '09-01-2014 00:01' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S' (match)
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: It seems that you are using the wrong format. Check whether your input data has seconds - you almost certainly do not want the `:%S` at the end of your format string.

Comment: What don't you understand about the error message?

Comment: Yeah I understand but in my data there is data like "4/30/2014 23:26:00" So that is why I use that format

Answer (score 0):

Look at your timestamp:
09-01-2014 00:01'

what does it say to you? hours and minutes, why do you put forward slashes instead of hyphens?

```
%m-%d-%Y-%H:%M
```